# Creating new page overwrites old page

Tags: blog, events

Every time we add something new, it deletes a previous entry, like its replacing it. Happened with blogs a few weeks ago then sorted itself out, now it is happening with events. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using loop before getting content from WordPress? Like this one:

```php
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

You content goes here

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not sure how this would address the issue? Your comment appears to refer more to retrieving posts... My issue is with creating posts, and having older posts overwritten after it is created.